# Adding fancybox to ruby on rails project guide

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I have found great tool which displays images. This exactly what I need to my project, but I am new at programming and I don't understand guide in their homepage : http://fancybox.net/howto

I have been looking in internet for step by step guide, but without a luck.

I would be very happy if someone could tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating Fancybox to Rails made fun with this [fancybox-rails](https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails) gem.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});  

Where I need to put this?

Comment: This can be place in your application.js.Then in your html for all <a> tag for which you need to apply fancybox effect add <a class="fancybox" href="#">link</a>

Comment: if you want to discuss join my room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10226/soundar

Comment: I need 20 reputation to talk in you room :(